# Excelに値を入力する際の問題

Tags: python, python3

ディレクトリ内にあるテキストファイルを読み込んで分かち書きし、それをEXCELに格納するプログラムを作成しています。
実行すると、読み込んだ最後のデータのみが出力され、残りのデータが出力・格納されません。
おそらくfor文で不具合が出ていると思い、試してみたのですがなかなかうまく行かず・・・
なにか解決策があればご教示お願いいたします

```
import openpyxl as op
import os.path
import urllib.request
import pyautogui as pg
import subprocess
import time
import glob
from janome.tokenizer import Tokenizer

def main():

    text_list = glob.glob('./*.txt')
    for text in text_list:
        for i in range(1,5):
            text = text.lstrip('.\\')
            #print(text)
            with open(text) as txt:
                allf = txt.read()

            txt_base = allf.replace('\n','')
            txt_base = txt_base.replace('\r','')
            txt_base = ''.join(txt_base.split())
            #print(txt_base)

            t = Tokenizer()
            with open(str(text)+'_wakati'+'.txt','w') as fw:
                for token in t.tokenize(txt_base,wakati = True):
                    fw.write(str(token))
                    fw.write('  ')

        with open(str(text)+'_wakati'+'.txt') as ow:
            wakati_data = ow.read()
            print(wakati_data)
            wb = op.load_workbook('hoge.xlsx')
            ws = wb.active
            ws['D'+str(i)].value = wakati_data
    wb.save('hoge.xlsx')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

インデントの問題ではないでしょうか。xlsxファイルへの書き込みを行う部分は、変数`i`で回しているforループの内側にいる必要があるように思います。

```
for text in text_list:
    for i in range(1,5):
    # 中略 #
        with open(str(text)+'_wakati'+'.txt') as ow:
            wakati_data = ow.read()
            print(wakati_data)
            wb = op.load_workbook('hoge.xlsx')
            ws = wb.active
            ws['D'+str(i)].value = wakati_data
            wb.save('hoge.xlsx')
```

質問文の書き方だと、ループをすべて抜けてからxlsxファイルに書き込みを行っています。
(二つ目の`for`ループとインデントレベルが揃ってしまっている)

Comment: 回答ありがとう御座います。回答をもとに修正をしましたが、出力がそれぞれ４回繰り返し行われ、excelへの格納もやはり最後に読み込んだtextファイルが4回入力されてしまっています。

Answer (score 0):

質問の処理で一番問題なのは、`for i in range(1,5):`とわけのわからない４回の繰り返しがあることです。Excelのセルの位置を決めるために`i`が必要なためと思われるので、とりあえず以下のように修正することで動作すると思います。他にも問題はあると思われますが、後は適当に修正してください。

```
from pathlib import Path # 追加のみ

def main():
    # 作成した *_wakati.txt をディレクトリに保存
    path = Path('./wakati')
    if not path.exists():
        path.mkdir()

    for text in Path('.').glob('*.txt'):
        with open(text) as txt:
            allf = txt.read()

            txt_base = allf.replace('\n','')
            txt_base = txt_base.replace('\r','')
            txt_base = ''.join(txt_base.split())

            t = Tokenizer()
            with open(path / (text.stem + '_wakati' + '.txt'), 'w') as fw:
                for token in t.tokenize(txt_base,wakati = True):
                    fw.write(str(token))
                    fw.write('  ')

    # 保存した *_wakati.txt を取り出してExcelに書き込み    
    wb = op.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    i = 1
    for text in path.glob('*.txt'):
        with open(text) as ow:
            wakati_data = ow.read()
            ws['D'+str(i)].value = wakati_data
        i += 1
    wb.save('hoge.xlsx')
```